# Assembly MIPS how to read .bin file

Tags: assembly, mips

How to read a .bin file in MIPS assembly? I have this code.

I'm really stuck here, been trying to solve this for weeks and seem to have no progress at all.

````
.data
    myArray: .space 32000
    fin:   .asciiz "hundredints.bin"
    newLine: .asciiz "\n"
    buffer: .space 32000
.text

    li $v0, 13
    la $a0, fin
    li $a1, 0
    li $a2, 0
    syscall
    move $s6, $v0

    #read from file
    li   $v0, 14       # system call for read from file
    move $a0, $s6      # file descriptor 
    la   $a1, buffer   # address of buffer to which to read
    li   $a2, 32000    # hardcoded buffer length
    syscall            # read from file

    li  $v0, 4          # system Call for PRINT STRING
    la  $a0, buffer     # buffer contains the values
    syscall             # print int

    # Close the file 
    li   $v0, 16       # system call for close file
    move $a0, $s6      # file descriptor to close
    syscall            # close file```
````

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem is. In what way is the code you've shown us not doing what you expect it to do?

Comment: @Michael it was an example. I just need to know how to read a file (.bin) in MIPS assembly.

Comment: But you have some code, so why don't you just run it and see what happens?

Comment: @Michael I did run it but got a blank result.

Comment: Well, system call 4 prints a NUL-terminated string. I have no idea what your file contains, but unless it contains a string, system call 4 isn't an appropriate way of printing the contents. That doesn't really have anything to do with _reading_ the file though.

Comment: @Michael it worked, I guess!!!! Thanks a lot :)